# Can't change stock bootanimation to something else on my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge

Tags: samsung, boot-animation

So I rooted my device and I downloaded this app called "Boot Animations" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.boot.animations&hl=en
I found one I liked and installed it. From what I've seen the bootanimation.zip is in system/media. Which is where mine got installed so I placed the right permissions for it and rebooted my phone but my provider's animation keeps playing. So I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it is located somewhere else? My phone model is SMG935.

Comment: Many EOMs put the animation just as an executable in `/system/bin` or `/vendor/bin` which is run as an `init` service on boot. Your custom animation would play only if it's the stock `/system/bin/bootanimation` service.

Comment: But how would I make it work in such case? since mine is a zip file. Since yeah you're right I have a bootanimation there.

Comment: I don't have your device to provide a step-by-step guide. But in theory you have to enable `bootanim` `init` service and disable any other which shows boot animation.